# Why get this notice in PHP

Tags: php

> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP\processor.php on line 43
>
> Line 43 is: $extension = end(explode(".",
>   strtolower($_FILES['photoUpload']['name'])));

```
$allowedExts = array( "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" );
$extension = end(explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['photoUpload']['name'])));

$allowedType = array( "image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png" );

if( !in_array($_FILES['photoUpload']['type'], $allowedType) )
die ("<br>Unsupported file type!");

if( !in_array($extension, $allowedExts) )
die ("<br>Unsupported file extension!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value of `explode()` to a variable before passing it to `end`:

```
$explode = explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['photoUpload']['name']));
$extension = end($explode);
```

This is because `end` needs to have a reference and the result of `explode()` cannot be used as a reference.

> end — Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element

More information at http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php.

Comment: Very nicely worded

Answer (score 0):

You can also use following method to get extension

```
$fileExtension = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```